# Detect if ListView is displaying last item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Such a simple task, but i really can't find a way to do it. I need to know if a user displayed **ListView** is displaying the last item.

Someone approaches this problem with the event `Scroll` on the `ScrollBar.Scroll` event, but thats not my case: I need to check if **ListView**'s *last item* is visible when another totally unrelated custom event is triggered.

I did it with **TextBox** and its own method `.GetLastVisibleLineIndex()`, which is pretty handy, but I can't find any similar method with **ListView**.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. i solved at the end! Using the `IsFullyOrPartiallyVisible` function from this blog: http://munnaondotnet.blogspot.it/2011/09/is-item-is-visible-in-scroll-viewer.html

My ListView's name is ListViewData

```
try
{
    if (IsFullyOrPartiallyVisible((ListBoxItem)listViewData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listViewData.Items[listViewData.Items.Count - 1]), listViewData))
    {
        listViewData.SelectedIndex = listViewData.Items.Count - 1;
        listViewData.ScrollIntoView(listViewData.SelectedItem);
    }
}
catch { }
```

I Don't like to ask question and answer it in less than 10 minutes, but i was struggling on this from a couple days before asking here :)